# Access apache server B through apache server A from a remote computer C

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, port-forwarding, remote-access

In a single network **NETWORK-1**, I have two computers: **A** and **B**. Both have *apache* servers running (both **Debian 7**). I own the server **A**, let's say my home page is `http://computerA/index.html`. I can also access the other guy (**B**)'s page at `B:8080/bspage.php` in this same network. I actually have a link to that guy's page in my `index.html` page as:

`<a  href="http://B:8080/bspage.php">B-Guy's Link</a>`

When I am away, working on **another network**, I can port-forward my server through a gateway using:

`ssh -L 8888:A:80 gate@somegateway`

therefore I can now open my server page again as

`localhost:8888/index.html`

but that link `B-Guy's Link` doesn't work anymore (I think for obvious reasons)!

What I need is somehow ***map*** **B**'s link `http://B:8080/bspage.php` to my server **A**, so that when I access this link `B-Guy's Link` remotely it gets accessed through **A**'s ***apache*** port `80` and no additional port-forwarding of **B** should be required. Although even in that local network (**NETWORK-1**), I tried to do (from my computer **A**):

`ssh -L 9999:localhost:8080 root@B`

(by the way I have root access to `B` and root is the only user except www-data) but `localhost:9999/bspage.php` doesn't open on my browser on **A**!! Then I thought maybe I have to change the user from `root` to `www-data` but I don't know the password of `www-data` on **B** so couldn't do that.

I am very new to this whole business so I will really appreciate any help. I feel like this should not be too complicated but have no idea what I am missing!

Thanks
-NL

---

### UPDATE AND SOLUTION

[davidgo](https://superuser.com/a/1440987/1040882)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1440987/1040882) helped me a lot, I was able to go through a few tutorials like [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04) where I enabled these four modules through:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
```

last one gave me an error like `lbmethod_byrequests` not found or something but eventually didn't matter.

Then I restarted the server using

`service apache2 restart`

after that, I failed to achieve what looks so easy to achieve but didn't happen! But [this article](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/116-simple-apache-reverse-proxy-example) finally helped, but anyway I am going to describe it in details:

I had to modify the file:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`  or the symlink: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

inside the block:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   # blah blah some code...
</VirtualHost>
```

I inserted the following:

```
<Location /sometag >
        ProxyPass http://B:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://B:8080/
</Location>
```

where `something` is any string that you can use, better to use something that is meaningful...for example here best would be to use a tag like `bserver`, therefore my configuration file will look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       # blah blah some code...
       <Location /bserver >
        ProxyPass http://B:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://B:8080/
       </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

restart the server again

`service apache2 restart`

Another little change you have to make. In your page (maybe `index.html` or whatever) on **server A** you change the link to **B**'s page from

`<a  href="http://B:8080/bspage.php">B-Guy's Link</a>`

to

`<a  href="bserver/bspage.php">B-Guy's Link</a>`

notice the tag **bserver**, now you are done. If you now connect to **A** and forward the port **80** to your external computer as

`ssh -L 8888:A:80 gate@somegateway`

you will open your main **A**'s page as usually:

`localhost:8888/index.html`

but now if you click on that **B**'s link, you will be re-directed to the URL:

`localhost:8888/bserver/bspage.php`

done!

It's worth mentioning that, following this method you can build your **A** computer as your main (`frontend`) server behind which many internal (`backend`) servers reside and then you can access all of them remotely.

Comment: Don't update your question, post an answer

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to the problem.

I would be inclined to set a path or virtualhost on serverA which is proxied in server A to B. To do this I would use ProxyPass rules in Apache. (Google up on proxypass and mod_proxy)

Alternatively I would be inclined to scrap the SSH port forwarding and replace it with OpenVPN - ideally running on the router. This, if correctly set up will transparently allow secure access to the whole network.

A distant third option would be to replace your  SSH forward with an SSH based SOX proxy. (This functionality is built into SSH, but needs the browsers to be configured to use it)

Comment: I am very hopeful now and I would love to go with the first method! I have got this [tutorial]( https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04), I enabled necessary apache modules modules, restarted apache server. And wrote <VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://B:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://B:8080/
</VirtualHost>  in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
And in my A-server's `index.html` I have written `http://B:8080/bspage.php` but didn't work.

Comment: Do you maybe need a ServerName directive in the VirtualHost block?

Comment: Finally succeeded! Adding these:  ``  <Location /laser >
            ProxyPass http://B:8080/html
            ProxyPassReverse http://B:8080/html
        </Location>``
to the file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default  inside the block of ``<VirtualHost *:80> ... </VirtualHost>`` did the job! Your answer helped me tremendously, but I will update my question with the solution so that dummies like me can benefit but I will refer to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I just updated my question with a solution, but on the suggestion of [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/a/1440987/1040882), I am going to turn that into an answer. So here we go:

[davidgo](https://superuser.com/a/1440987/1040882)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1440987/1040882) helped me a lot, I was able to go through a few tutorials like [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04) where I enabled these four modules through:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
```

last one gave me an error like `lbmethod_byrequests` not found or something but eventually didn't matter.

Then I restarted the server using

`service apache2 restart`

after that, I failed to achieve what looks so easy to achieve but didn't happen! But [this article](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/116-simple-apache-reverse-proxy-example) finally helped, but anyway I am going to describe it in details:

I had to modify the file:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`  or the symlink: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

inside the block:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   # blah blah some code...
</VirtualHost>
```

I inserted the following:

```
<Location /sometag >
        ProxyPass http://B:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://B:8080/
</Location>
```

where `something` is any string that you can use, better to use something that is meaningful...for example here best would be to use a tag like `bserver`, therefore my configuration file will look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       # blah blah some code...
       <Location /bserver >
        ProxyPass http://B:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://B:8080/
       </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

restart the server again

`service apache2 restart`

Another little change you have to make. In your page (maybe `index.html` or whatever) on **server A** you change the link to **B**'s page from

`<a  href="http://B:8080/bspage.php">B-Guy's Link</a>`

to

`<a  href="bserver/bspage.php">B-Guy's Link</a>`

notice the tag **bserver**, now you are done. If you now connect to **A** and forward the port **80** to your external computer as

`ssh -L 8888:A:80 gate@somegateway`

you will open your main **A**'s page as usually:

`localhost:8888/index.html`

but now if you click on that **B**'s link, you will be re-directed to the URL:

`localhost:8888/bserver/bspage.php`

done!

It's worth mentioning that, following this method you can build your **A** computer as your main (`frontend`) server behind which many internal (`backend`) servers reside and then you can access all of them remotely.